# Cannot call method 'charAt' of undefined - only on server

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap, passenger, less, bootswatch

I have a rails application which is running well in local (OsX, WEBrick).

I've cloned the repo on a server (Ubuntu 10.04, Apache, Passenger), setted up passenger, but now when i try to connect to every page i get

```
Less::ParseError in Pages#home

Showing /var/www/MYAPP/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #5 raised:

Cannot call method 'charAt' of undefined
  (in /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/twitter-bootstrap-rails-2.0.2/vendor/assets/stylesheets/twitter/bootstrap.css.less)
```

the content of bootstrap.css.less is:

```
@import "twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap";
```

line 5 of application.html.erb is:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application" %>
```

ruby 1.8.7 on both machines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solved upgrading to ruby 1.9.3

Answer (score 1):

Upgrading less worked for me on Ubuntu server 10.04

For system wide:

```
sudo npm -g install less
```

For user only:

```
npm install less
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this has something to do with the Ruby less gem not compiling it correctly.  I had this problem locally on mac as well.  Somewhere I saw a suggestion to use the node version of less (1.3) instead of the ruby gem, which you can install with `npm install less`.

However, most of the gems that hook up bootstrap to rails use the ruby gem version, so it seemed like a no go, esp on heroku etc.  After a very frustrating couple of days on this I gave up and switch to the sass version of bootstrap: https://github.com/thomas-mcdonald/bootstrap-sass

It was simpler to integrate with rails, but unfortunate to be off the official version of bootstrap.  I later went to integrate bootswatch but this doesn't play well with sass either.  So I'm back to the plain old css version of bootswatch for now until a better way to handle this comes out :/